# pipenv hangs with no output when creating new virtual environment in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv

If I type `pipenv`, `pipenv shell`, `pipenv install`, or any other command that triggers creating a new environment, it hangs forever (tested for 10 minutes) without displaying any output at all. If I do a command where there is already a pipenv virtual environment created, it has no problem (e.g. updating from the Pipfile or running the shell). I suspect the problem is specific to running on WSL Ubuntu (Ubuntu subsystem for Windows), but I'm not sure how to verify that.

The reason I was able to verify that pipenv commands worked fine on an existing pipenv virtual environment was because I didn't have this problem a few months ago, and I already had a successfully created virtual environment. I ran into this problem today when trying to create an environment for a new project. But after removing the virtual environment in the still working project and trying to re-create that environment, it failed the same way as it did for the new project. Hanging with no output.

`pyenv` is confirmed to work.

Output of `pyenv versions` (both projects have `python_full_version` set to something in this list):

```
system
3.7.10
* 3.8.12 (set by /home/dcripplinger/.pyenv/version)
```

Output of `which pipenv` (also confirmed there is not a duplicate pipenv installed with apt):

```
/home/dcripplinger/.local/bin/pipenv
```

`pipenv` was installed with `pip install --user pipenv`, which I believe lines up correctly with the above location. I also confirmed there is not currently a duplicate pipenv installed with apt (although there used to be).

Output of `pip --version` (indicating it's using the correct global pyenv):

```
pip 21.1.1 from /home/dcripplinger/.pyenv/versions/3.8.12/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Output of `virtualenv --version`:

```
virtualenv 20.9.0 from /home/dcripplinger/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

This is not related to the Pipfile or Pipfile.lock in the two projects because the same thing happens in a new folder making a blank environment with a simple command like `pipenv --three`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? 
I have this issue too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one needs to declare the python version first (even though I've got it declared in the Pipfile already :shrug:).

e.g.

```
pipenv --python 3.6
```

And only then

```
pipenv install
```

(fwiw: I actually had to `sudo` both of those, but, I assume that's not best practice).

Answer (score 1):

Declaring python didn't make any difference to me, but setting this variable fixed the problem:

```
SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib pipenv install
```

**Note:** It takes some time to get going and doesn't output right away so wait a few minutes before giving up on it!